# How to draw internal energy-entropy curve in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reproduce the attached internal energy-entropy curve in Tikz.

How can I do this?
Getting a smooth curve with the correct form is quite difficult for me.[image: Energy-Entropy Curve in Tikz]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does the curve need to be exact and if yes, how is it defined? From your question, I take it that you are stuck with drawing the curve. Maybe you can show what you got so far? It will be easier to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are interested in trying an alternative drawing system, here is a version of your diagram in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html). (If you follow this link you will find tutorials, examples, and reference material).

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib`, so you need to use the `lualatex` engine to compile it.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    z1 = (5mm, 5mm);
    z2 = (5cm, 6cm);

    path curve; 
    curve = z1 {dir 10} .. {dir 80} z2;

    pair A, B, C;
    B = point 1/4 of curve;
    C = point 1/2 of curve;
    A = (xpart B, ypart C);

    path axes; 
    axes = (0, y2) -- (0, 0) -- (x2, 0);

    draw (0, ypart C) .. C;
    draw B .. A;
    draw curve withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw axes;

    label.llft("\textsf{U}", point 0 of axes);
    label.llft("\textsf{S}", point 2 of axes);

    label.top("$A$", A);
    label.lrt("$B$", B);
    label.lrt("$C$", C);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```